# Can I embed a Power BI dashboard in Github wiki page?

Tags: powerbi, github-pages, powerbi-embedded

Is it possible to  embed PowerBI dashboard to github wiki page?
Thanks,

Comment: See if you can stick inside an iframe. It's probably not supported but it might work

Answer (score 1):

Apparently not: the [About GitHub Wikis](https://help.github.com/articles/about-github-wikis/) page lists what you can embed (like links or images).

External elements are not supported (unless you embed an image copy of that dashboard)